# Apex - PageReference - Report URL

Tags: apex, reporting, pagereference, csv, excel

When our org was in classic, we had the below code which used to save a report as an Attachment. This has worked for the past 7 years...

```
PageReference reportLink = new PageReference('/'+reportId+'?excel=printable_view');
Attachment reportAtt = new Attachment();                
reportAtt.Name = reportName+'_'+df+'.xls';
reportAtt.Body = reportLink.getContent();
reportAtt.ParentId = parentId;
reportAtt.ContentType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
insert reportAtt;
```

Obviously the URL slightly changed in Lightning to '/' + reportId + '?excel=1&exp=1&isdtp=p1' and we now use files rather than attachments.

However the content of the Excel file now looks like the below...

[image]

So I tried exporting as a CSV, and get the below...

[image]

Any ideas? In a nutshell, we want to run and save reports at a point in time, not scheduled, not emailed but when a user clicks go through a process.

We've looked into ReportDataCapure, but it doesn't quite give us what we need. We have also started investigating using Reports.ReportResults, Metadata etc... but before we end up down a coding rabbit hole and use up dev resource... wondered if any wizards out there might know the easy answer!